# Filtering the extract of a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pypdf

I am currently extracting data from a pdf.

My code is able to extract each line of that [PDF](https://www.211qc.ca/action/211/montreal2-fr.pdf).

What I want is:

1. to extract some information, ie: 'Téléc', 'Courriel', 'Territoire desservi'
2. to have the data that matches such information, ie: Téléc = 579-240-XXX, and so on.

**Here is my code, and what can we do to filter my extract?**

*Code:*

```
import PyPDF2
pdfileObj = xxxxxxxxxxxx
pdf = open(pdfileObj, 'rb')

pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfileObj)
pageObj = pdfreader.getPage(10)
text = pageObj.extract_text()

for words in text:
    search_keywords = ['Téléc', 'Courriel', 'Territoire desservi']
    print(text)
```

Comment: `to have the data that matches such information` What kind of data?

Please provide an example fo the data you whish to extract and how it is formatted in the PDF.

Comment: Hello @BobserLuck, thank you for your questions. Actually, I want to extract both int and float data.Ex: name of the association: RÉSEAU-BÉNÉVOLE DE VERDUN, Telec: 514 761-1020, Site internet: www.reseau-benevoles-verdun.org, Territoire desservi: Verdun, Île-des-Soeurs

Comment: Here is the document where I have to extract data: https://www.211qc.ca/action/211/montreal2-fr.pdf